# How to Verify toast message in mobile screen if its showing after invalid Login

Tags: android, testing, automation, appium, appium-android

I want to verify toast message which appears on screen after entering wrong login data.
Error message showing is   invalid credentials.
I also want to print Error message in Eclipse console
I am automating mobile App using Appium.

pls let me know java code for that.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to this problem:

One, You can simply wrap the entire process of Toast creation in a function called createErrorToast() as it will take care of your logging condition and you can check if that function was called or not.

```
fun createErrorToast(): Toast {
  System.out.println("error toast created")

  return Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);  
}
```

Two, You can use Espresso UI testing library to verify that the Toast View actually gets inflated and the user does certain actions on it.